# What is the most basic kind of item/template that can exist in Sitecore?

Tags: templates, content-management

I have a need to store simple string values in the Sitecore `content tree`.  I am thinking i'd like to create the most basic kind of Sitecore item with the least amount of fields.  But, if I select [`none`] for Templates, it still always adds the `Standard Template`, which has a dozen `inherited` sections/fields.

Is it possible to create a more basic template/data item in Sitecore?  Or are all of those `standard template` fields required for system-level `processes`?

I understand from a SQL data perspective, most of those other fields aren't actually saved when creating a new simple item.  But, mostly was just curious what the most basic kind of item could be in Sitecore, since I really only need to store a `Display Name`.

Comment: The Sitecore standard template defines a base template for most other data templates.So it's recommended to inherit the standard template for good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Technically removing the standard template from the base template of your custom template will not create any issues at system level. **But you will be missing the out of box features something like setting the presentation details, Workflow, Insert Options etc.**

If you don't need the out of box features or your requirement is just to create the data item in Sitecore without any system fields then you can set the base template as null for the custom template which you want to create. To do this, **check the "Raw Values" in "View" menu and then Go to Data Section of your custom template and update the base template as "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"**. For Ex, this is how the Sitecore templates under /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Sections are created to avoid circular reference when inherited in standard template. [image]

> There are lot many options which uses the standard template will not
>   be shown when you remove the inheritance, once you removed the inheritance just select
>   the item and navigate each and every menu like "Home", "Navigate" etc in the menu bar, you
>   will notice many are missing as I said above.

So consider all the above before removing the standard template.